# Swift: NSString not convertible to 'String'

Tags: ios, string, swift

I am new to Swift and I am trying to return a group of rows into an array, but now I am trapped in a circle of errors. Any help would be appreciated. I am probably missing something, but it sure does not feel like it:

**EDIT: Added code (Constraints for arrays not set).**

```
func createButtonWithTitle(title: String) -> UIButton {

    let button = UIButton(type:.System) as UIButton
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
    button.sizeToFit()
    button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)

    return button
}

func createRowOfButtons(buttonTitles: [NSString]) -> UIView {

    var buttons = [UIButton]()
    let keyboardRowView = UIView()

    for buttonTitle in buttonTitles{

        let button = createButtonWithTitle(buttonTitle as String)
        buttons.append(button)
        keyboardRowView.addSubview(button)
    }

    addIndividualButtonConstraints(buttons, mainView: keyboardRowView)

    return keyboardRowView
}

func createArraysOfButtons (rowTitles: [NSString]) -> UIView{

    var rows = [UIView]()
    let keyArrayView = UIView()

    for rowTitle in rowTitles {
        if let title = rowTitle as? String{
            let row = createRowOfButtons(rowTitle as String)
            rows.append(row)
            keyArrayView.addSubview(row)
        }
    }
    return keyArrayView
}
```

Error Message:

> 'NSString' is not implicitly convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?

Comment: Why don't you change the parameter type to [String]?

Comment: @LeoDabus tried that and got another error: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '[NSString]'

Comment: @LeoDabus I also did this in another function to return the rows, so there is not reason for this not to work.

Comment: Stop posting screenshots!!

Comment: @LeoDabus would only let me add one at a time for some reason.

Comment: You shouldn't post any.  Post your code.

Comment: @Geppelt I have an answer prepared to submit that will answer your question, however I will not post it until you replace the images by the actual code and a quote of the error. The images you posted can disappear at any time, making both the question and my answer invalid/

Comment: @Geppelt please don't add the whole code, add only the pieces that cause the problems - i.e. the ones from the screenshots. And also add the error messages.

Comment: In Swift don't use `NSString` at all unless you have absolutely no choice. Use always the native `String` type

Comment: @vadian The issue when I do not use NSString is: Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'

Comment: The main issue is that you call `createRowOfButtons(rowTitle as String)` with a single object, but the method signature expects an array.

Comment: @Vadian I define those elsewhere. Currently I have 4 rows of 7, not I am trying to add a second set. That is all.

Comment: Again: the error `Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType` occurs when you pass type `String` to expected type `[String]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution: **Do not use NSString**

```
func createRowOfButtons(buttonTitles: [String]) -> UIView {

    var buttons = [UIButton]()
    let keyboardRowView = UIView()

    for buttonTitle in buttonTitles{

        let button = createButtonWithTitle(buttonTitle)
        buttons.append(button)
        keyboardRowView.addSubview(button)
    }

    addIndividualButtonConstraints(buttons, mainView: keyboardRowView)

    return keyboardRowView
}

func createArraysOfButtons (rowTitles: [String]) -> UIView{

    var rows = [UIView]()
    let keyArrayView = UIView()

    for rowTitle in rowTitles {
        let row = createRowOfButtons([rowTitle])
        rows.append(row)
        keyArrayView.addSubview(row)
    }
    return keyArrayView
}
```

The main issue is that `createRowOfButtons` expects an array of string but you're passing a single string to the method. `createRowOfButtons([rowTitle])` solves that issue.

Comment: I am getting a single error: Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected element type 'String'